# How to detect keyboard input is possible in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, gamepad

I'm currently trying to build an app to use the Xbox360 controller on my pc. I've got it up and running that I can detect when buttons are pressed etc, but I now want to take it a step further and try to create my own on-screen keyboard specifically for the gamepad.

My question is: Is there any way in Windows(using c# or even c++) to detect when a user is able to type in text?

An example would be my app would be running in the background, then if a user was to open up internet explorer and click in the address bar, my app would popup and they can use the gamepad to enter in text.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to check if there is a keyboard connected?

Comment: @DavidPilkington I believe he is trying to say, when you click on the address bar (a place to enter text) a keyboard pops up on the screen where the user can type using their controller.

Comment: gleng is mostly right. I want to know if there's some way to tell that a user has now selected a field that text can be entered into. This field would exist on another app on the pc, any other app. I'd then use my app to provide my own onscreen keyboard allowing the user to type using the gamepad.